# If I use specific time, how to get other local's time

Tags: node.js, date, timezone

If I define a specific time, how to get other local's time?

I use node.js and I know module (date-utils, moment-timezone). I will use some parameters (e.g. year, month, day, hour, minutes) and I want to get other country's time.

For example my server's local is America and I use a parameter (not real time specific time I want, and its my local's time) to server.

If I want to get Korean local time, what should I do?

If I want Korean's time 2015 07 07 11 11 and I will have 2015 07 07 11 11
how to get the Korean time from server?